# What happens when flying on a Victor airway but through a class B or C airspace?

Tags: faa-regulations, airspace

I think it´s a very simple doubt but also very important, and i can´t find the answer. If you are flying on a Federal Airway that at some point cross a class B airspace (for example)...do you need authorization or can you keep flying without one?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! Are you asking about VFR or IFR?

Comment: Ask for Flight Following on your flights, they will more than likely help you out in those situations.

Answer (score 5):

If you are flying your IFR flight plan which you got clearance for, then you have permission already.
If you are flying VFR you need to ask ATC for clearance.
Class B airspace requires clearance for all traffic and separation is also provided by ATC for all traffic.